# Is it ok if I pass through a RJ11 (Phone line) cable outside and leave it while it is raining?

Tags: wiring, low-voltage, telephone, phone-wiring

I'm stupid and paranoid  but just to make sure, is it safe to leave a phone lines (rj11 I think) outside while raining, the front and end BIT is inside the house (forgot what it's called, the bit where u plug it into somethin).

Comment: Is this temporary? Permanent? Can you provide more details about what you're doing here? Generally speaking, a standard phone line can last a short while outside, but long term is another story

Comment: It's supposed to be permanent

Comment: Solar radiation is eventually going to destroy the wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RJ11 is actually the name of the connector specification.

Wire/insulation and cable jacket materials vary for the specific purpose.  Phone wire may also need to be thicker (e.g., lower gauge than Cat 5e) for longer runs, to avoid excessive voltage drop, depending upon your system.

There are phone cables specifically intended for outdoor use, providing better sun and water protection.  It could then be wired to a properly protected RJ11 receptacle, also designed for outdoor use.  I would not recommend using unapproved electrical wiring outdoors - even for phones. The phone company typically puts somewhere between 50 to 150 volts AC down that wire to make the phone ring.

Comment: Right..... That's a bit more serious, thanks. I have also bought a 5m Cat 6 cables for a different purpose. Is that better or the same?

Comment: You can buy Cat 6 UTP that is rated for outdoor use.

Comment: Ok cheers for answer

Answer (score 1):

If this is permanent, I would get some 1/2" conduit and bury Cat 5e Ethernet (4 phone lines if you so desire). That way the wire isn't likely to be damaged.